# How to set a Postgresql password for super user?

Tags: postgresql

I compiled Postgresql 9.5.3 and then installed it (Windows). I called initdb, then started the server. It created a user with name of the Windows user. It allows login without or with incorrect password. How to specify a password? ALTER USER test WITH PASSWORD 'x'; does not work.

Comment: You probably have that user in your pg_hba.conf file as `trust` and need to change it to `md5`

Comment: that worked. thanks